How to use C++/WinRT API as part of C++ DLL without relying on the UWP UI portion?
I am attempting to utilize the C++/WinRT code provided in the sample of LampArray, cppwinrt to create a C++ DLL. However due to the tight coupling of this sample with the UI, I am not able to use below API independently within my DLL code, without incorporating UI Code.
m_deviceAddedRevoker = m_deviceWatcher.Added(winrt::auto_revoke, { get_weak(), &Scenario1_Basics::Watcher_Added});
m_deviceRemovedRevoker = m_deviceWatcher.Removed(winrt::auto_revoke, { get_weak(), &Scenario1_Basics::Watcher_Removed });

Could anyone please guide me on whether there's a method to directly invoke the API in my C++ DLL code without relying on the UWP UI portion? Note: I am trying to create a C++ DLL to access the lamp devices attached to system like lights/LEDs, etc.

The device watcher doesn't depend on a UI. If you don't want to incorporate the UI code, don't. I believe the calling thread needs to have a dispatcher queue to bring the event delegates to life (see CreateDispatcherQueueController() for more information).

@sunil - DeviceWatcher works on any thread (events are also coming also from any thread, not UI threads). Stupid question but have you called Start? Otherwise please post a reproducing sample How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Will using Windows Runtime components meet your needs? You can refer to this blog use Windows Runtime Components in Desktop Apps.

Hi, @SimonMourier, Yes DeviceWatcher doesn't depend on the UI but when I call using LampArray::GetDeviceSelector() as below  then getting the compilation error (get_weak: identifier not found ) while i have added the required header file which is in base.h,   Yes I have called Start.
m_deviceWatcher=DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(LampArray::GetDeviceSelector());
m_deviceAddedRevoker = m_deviceWatcher.Added(winrt::auto_revoke, { get_weak(), Watcher_Added });
m_deviceWatcher.Start();

@sunil - Please provide a minimal reproducible sample (by code or somewhere on internet), not code in comments

get_weak() is a class member of the implements class template. If you are getting compiler errors you're probably calling it from a class that doesn't implement a Windows Runtime type.

If you don't want to derive from implements, you can derive your class from std::enable_shared_from_this and use weak_from_this. Or just use a lambda and do your own lifetime management.

@RaymondChen,  in order to utilize get_weak(), I need to derive from winrt::implements() since it's declared within that scope. From what I comprehend, std::enable_shared_from_this and weak_from_this are associated with shared and weak pointers. Alternatively, if you could direct me to a resource where I can access lamp devices such as lights/LEDs, etc.  using  c++, irrespective of the UI, that would be greatly appreciated."

You don't need to use any pointer at all. The event handler can just be a lambda. m_deviceWatcher.Added([](auto&& sender, auto&& info) { printf("Device added: %ls\n", info.Id().c_str(); }); The weak pointer is just an example of how to access the container class. It's not part of the API. If you have other ways of accessing the container class, then you are welcome to use them.
